# Change of variables problem.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

[image]

We're given a normal xy - plane , with the help of the transformations $ u = x^{2} - y^{2}$ and $v = 2xy$ , we need to plot the corresponding image in the $uv$-plane.

First we need to find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$ ,

By completing the square , I got : $ (x^{2} + y^{2})^{2} = u^{2} + v^{2}$

=> $ x^{2} + y^{2} = \sqrt{u^{2} + v^{2}}$.

If I try to find equations for $x$ and $y$ from this , the situation becomes messy ..

Can anyone suggest a better way ?

Update : Using the equations $y = 2x$ and $y=4$ ,  I got the equations in $u$ and $v$ as : $v= (\dfrac{-4}{3}) u$ and $v^{2} = 64(u + 16)$ , and I was able to draw a graph as follows :

[image]

(I know that doesn't look like a parabola , but still.. )

Now I am not able to find the image of the line $ y = 2x - 10$ , I tried solving $ u = x^{2} - y^{2}$ and $v = 2xy$ for the given $y$ but the equation ends up in terms of $x$ only.. Could anyone help ?

Comment: The image seems to be not related to the question. Is it?

Comment: You want to plot the image of what? Please try to write a clear question.

Comment: The question is (I guess) to find the image of the parallelogram under the mapping $(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)$.

Comment: The mapping looks easier in the complex plane: $u+iv=(x+iy)^2$.

Comment: The image of the above graph is required tin the $uv$-plane.. @EmanuelePaolini

Answer (score 2):

Consider the substitution $x = r\cosh t, y = r\sinh t$.

Added:

$$u = x^2-y^2 =r^2\cosh^2 t - r^2\sinh^2t =r^2$$
$$v = 2xy =2 (r\cosh t)(r\sinh t) = r^2(2\cosh t\sinh t) = r^2\sinh 2t$$

So
$$ r = \sqrt u$$
$$ t = \frac 1 2 \sinh^{-1} \frac v u$$
and
$$ x = \sqrt u \cosh\left(\frac 1 2 \sinh^{-1} \frac v u\right)$$
$$ y = \sqrt u \sinh\left(\frac 1 2 \sinh^{-1} \frac v u\right)$$

Not very pretty, but it does express $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$.

Comment: Actually the transformations are already given , 
I have made some changes , could you help ?

Comment: I was not suggesting a different transformation. It was a method for solving for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$. See the addendum to my post. Unfortunately, it is not all that helpful in your graph, though (assuming that you are graphing by hand).

Answer (score 2):

Try building some intuition by watching what happens to the vertices and sides of the quadrilateral under the change-of-variables transformation $T(x,y) = (x^2-y^2, 2xy)$.

**Example for an vertex:**
$T(5,0) = (25,0)$

You should be able to easily find all the images of your vertices this way.  The only question that remains is what are the shapes of the curves that connect these vertices.

**Example for a side:** 
One side of the quadrilateral is defined by the curve $y=2x$ for $x \in [0,2]$.  You can think of this as a parametrized curve defined by the points$(x,2x)$ for $x \in [0,2]$.  Now watch what happens under the transformation:

$T(x,2x) = (\;(x)^2-(2x)^2, \;2(x)(2x)\;) = (-3x^2, 4x^2)$, still for $x \in [0,2]$.

When drawing a parametric curve, you are not obligated to move your pencil at a linear rate.  That is to say, you can re-parametrize the curve with $a=x^2$ without changing the curve itself.  Now you have $(-3a,4a)$ for $a \in [0,4]$.  Can you draw that?